# Formas de hacer una pagina web dinámica con html5 y jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, aplicación-web

lo que quiero hacer es que teniendo 2 paginas web pueda cargar elementos como un div de la segunda pagina en la primera, llevo ya un tiempo buscando una solución y solo he encontrado soluciones parciales, como esta:

`$('#registro').on('click', function() { $("#loader1").load('elementos.php #registro-usuario'); });`

el problema de este script es que después tengo, por ejemplo

```
$('#pedidos').on('click', function() {
$("#loader1").load('elementos.php #pedidos');
  });
```

Al hacer clic sobre el botón pedidos no hace nada.

La segunda opción que encontré es usar addeventlistener, pero todo lo que he logrado con esto es modificar el innerHtml para que muestre un mensaje cualquiera y no el contenido de los div que necesito que muestre.
No tengo el script de esto en este momento porque lo borré.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que querés es agregar datos de una página (ORIGIN) a otra (TARGET), se me ocurren dos opciones:

**OPCION 1:**

Si conocés TARGET (esto es: si target lo abriste, suponete, con window.open), podés usar "postMessage". Suponete, algo así:

En ORIGIN:

```
 const TARGET = window.open("...");
    ....
    const elemento1={text : "Sarasa", id: "35"};
    TARGET.postMessage(elemento1,'*');
```

Luego, en TARGET, lo levantás así:

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    if (event.origin !== "http://example.com:8080")
    return;

    // agregar el elemento por jquery
    myCustomJqueryFunctionToAddElement(event.data);
});
  
}, false);
```

Para más info, mirate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

---

**OPCION 2:**

En ORIGIN guardás el contenido en localStorage:

```
const elemento1={text : "Sarasa", id: "35"};
localStorage.setItem('elemento1', elemento1);
```

En TARGET agregás un listener a los cambios de estado del localStorage:

```
window.onstorage = () => {
  // Cuando localStorage cambie, agregar el elemento
  const elemento = window.localStorage.getItem('elemento1'));
  myCustomJqueryFunctionToAddElement(elemento);
};
```

Obviamente, mis códigos son de sugerencia. Deberías customizarlo para que cuando agregues el elemento, lo borre del storage, también podrías asegurarte de que el elemento no haya sido agregado en el html antes de agregarlo, etc...

Pero creo que lo que necesitabas saber era "como comunicar entre ventanas abiertas", y esas son las formas que se me ocurren.

Comment: la verdad intente implementar ambos y no pude son muchos elementos nuevos para mi y no acabo de entenderlos bien.